# devcontainer extension auto not installing

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I have the following code in my devcontainer.json

```
{
  "name": "Python 3",
  "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/python:0-3.11",

  "customizations": {
    "vscode": {
        "extensions": [
            "ms-python.python",
            "ms-python.vscode-pylance",
            "ms-python.black-formatter"
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

The container starts but the extensions does not auto install.
I can manually install them once container is running.

The only log error I can see is the below but not sure that is the root cause.

```
Error: stream ended with:0 but wanted:9
    at c (c:\Users\bob\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.292.0\dist\extension\extension.js:24:101670)
    at c:\Users\bob\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.292.0\dist\extension\extension.js:24:101851
    at s (c:\Users\bob\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.292.0\dist\extension\extension.js:27:5371)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (c:\Users\bob\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.292.0\dist\extension\extension.js:27:5541)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1358:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
[2023-05-11T12:53:21.754Z] Could not connect to WSL.
```

Any advice on what is causing the issue?